# xlsxwriter: How to change scatter chart subtype for single add_series()?

Tags: xlsxwriter

I define a scatter chart using subtype smooth and add some data:

```
chart1 = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'scatter', 'subtype' : 'smooth'})
Sname = "=Measurement_dBV!%s1" %(row_list[i])
chart.add_series({
   'name':         Sname,
   'categories':   ['Measurement_dBV',1,0,numData,0],
   'values':       ['Measurement_dBV',1,i+1,numData,i+1],
   'line': {'width': 1.0, 'color': color_list[i]},
})
```

This works fine. But now I need to add two other data lines to the same chart but in this case the lines must be a subtype of straight.
My first idea was to use "combine". But the documentation say, that a chart of type scatter can´t be the primary chart as well as the combined chart is the same type.

So: How to change the subtype for a single data series?

In Excel you can define different types of charts an it´s subtypes for every single data series.

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Best Regards
Karsten

Answer (score 1):

In XlsxWriter if your chart subtype is `smooth` then you can turn it off for an individual series using the [smooth chart option](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_charts.html#chart-series-option-smooth):

```py
        # Add a smooth scatter chart.
        chart = workbook.add_chart({
            'type': 'scatter',
            'subtype': 'smooth'
        })

        # Add a series with default smooth.
        chart.add_series({
            'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5',
            'values': '=Sheet1!$B$1:$B$5',
        })

        # Add a series with smooth turned off.
        chart.add_series({
            'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5',
            'values': '=Sheet1!$C$1:$C$5',
            'smooth': False,
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot!

Simple as it is, but you have to know it...
GREAT!

regards
Karsten